# Automatic startup of instances in Fabric8 or JbossFuse

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, dsl, jbossfuse, fabric8

We made up application on top of Fabric8 ( OSGI bundles, Features and Profiles ) which is installable through Fabric Profiles and local mvn proxy. So far so good, instances are created, application runs fine etc...

However, if the host where the instance is running is restarted, then the instances won't startup again. Fabric can be instantiated as a service, but not the instances which are monitored through the root container.

So what would be the best way to make instances load on startup, or is there a way to do that, or we have to figure it out our way?

Thanks, 
Tiho

Answer (score 2):

You can use the scripting commands to do this. The bin directory contains a client that you can use to connect to a running fuse instance and run commands against it. In your case you would use it this way:

`bin/client -r 60 container-start child`

The `-r 60` part tells the client to keep retrying the connection if fuse isn't running yet. This option allows you to run this command in the same script immediately after starting the root container. Of course it won't be started by then, but the `-r 60` option makes sure it will wait for the root container to start, and then run the command to start the child containers.